# jquery toggle alternative, couldn't understand what's happening here

Tags: jquery, ajax, smarty

It may seem to be very easy for you guys but I'm kinda new in jquery and ajax. I've looked everywhere and couldn't solve the problem for hours. My problem is the following ;

I have a html link with class name follow

```
<a href="#" class="follow">  {if $is_following == 0} follow {else} following {/if}  </a>
```

the if-else statement is just a smarty template engine usage. it's very simple. if the user is following other user, then show 'follow' value, else show 'following' value.

My jquery is the following ;

```
var $values;
$('.follow').mouseover(
    function()
    {
        $values = $(this).html();
        if($values == 'following')
        {
            $(this).html('unfollow');
        }
    }
);

$('.follow').mouseout(

    function()
    {
        $(this).html($values);
    }
);

$('.follow').toggle(

    function(){
        $(this).html('following');
        $values = "following";
    },
    function(){
        $(this).html('follow');
        $values = "follow";     
    }
);

//follow ajax call    
$('.follow').click(function(){

    var $op = $(this).html();
    var $other_profile_id = $('#other_profile_id').text();

    if($op == 'follow')
    {                   
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : 'ajax_service.php',
            dataType : 'json', 
            data: {
                op : $op,
                other_profile_id : $other_profile_id
            },          
            success : function(data){               

            },
            error:function (error){
                console.error(error.responseText);
            }                                   
        });                 
    }
    else if($op == 'unfollow')
    {               
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : 'ajax_service.php',
            dataType : 'json',
            data: {
                op : $op,
                other_profile_id : $('#other_profile_id').text()            
            },
            success : function(data){
            },
            error:function (error){
                console.error(error.responseText);
            }   
        });
    }
});
```

EDIT : Based on answer, I need to explain functionality;

- If a user is not followed, the link shows 'follow' value.
- If the user has already followed, 'following' value is showed, it should fire the mouseover event when mouse is over the link.
- If mouse is over the link and the value is 'following', then the link value should be 'unfollow'.
- If mouse is out on the link it should show the value 'following' again.
- If the user is not followed, it shows 'follow' value on link.

I don't want to use toggle event. Because toggle just catches the first and second click. I need an if statement which controls whether link value is follow or following.

Moreover, if the user follows, it shows following value but mouseover event doesn't work. Can you please explain me why ? I couldn't understand what's happening here.

Any suggestions or helps will be appreciated.

P.S : If I remove toggle event and control the value of link inside ajax calls, it doesn't work at all.

Moreover, I'm thinking to assign different link id s to links and handle them seperately. But, I think it is the wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In several places you have statements of the form:

```
$(this).html();
```

OR

```
$(this).html('sometext');
```

If you change these to:

```
$(this).text(); 

$(this).text('newtext');
```

does this resolve your issue?

NOTE: 'newtext' would be whatever text you wish to be held within that tag.

EDIT NOTE2: I KNOW that is not ALL of your issues, but perhaps you could explain your desired functionality a little more clearly.

See this fiddle to determine if that is what you are looking for:  http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/Swp7x/

NOTE: it uses jsonp and cross domain and simply uses the returned value echoed back, but you can get the ajax part working as needed for you.  I put in a field to show the value of the current state visually to perhaps help you understand the workings.

Comment: it doesn't change anything when I change $(this).html(); to $(this).text();

Comment: I've added the functionality to question.

Comment: it's quite what I want but I have a question. is post data also converted to json or not ?

Comment: Well, how can I handle that ajax request in php ? Can you also explain that ?